# max-width in div to make responsive design not working

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have a problem with my div to make a page with RWD. I need that my div has max-width: 800px So when resize the browser, the div also resizes and having a maximum is 800px, but doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container>
    <div class="show-section">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="show-section">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="show-section">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #fffff7;
    font: 16px/22px Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

**max-width: 800px**

[image]

**width: 70%**

[image]

When it reaches the 720 approx. not resized and is not as it should be centered on the screen, but if instead of max-width: 800px; would put width: 70% works. But I do not want it that way because when the screen is too large, so is the div and so I would like to have a size limit.

Comment: Why not specify a media query? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Yes, I put a media-query but for other components.. but in other project I have css something like that and works perfectly without mediaqueries

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question, but have you simply tried `width:70%;max-width:800px;`?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to work for me, I just needed to add a little double quote after the 'container' ID.

```
<div id="container>
```

To

```
<div id="container">
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mUCSz/1/. Just resize the preview pane.

Comment: @SoldierCorp could also modify the `margin` to be `margin:50px auto 0;`

Comment: Is rare :/ in jsfiddle works fine.. may affect other properties .. respect "container, just forget close quotes.